# BitmapSource to InteropBitmap

Tags: c#

I made some research but i'm unable to find a way to convert a BitmapSource to InteropBitmap.

```
System.Windows.Interop.InteropBitmap MyBitmap;
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource _currentFrame = /* get the frame */;

MyBitmap = Convert(_currentFrame);
```

How can I do the Convert method ?

Comment: According to MSDN [InteropBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.interopbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) inherits from `BitmapSource`, so you shouldn't need to convert; just use the `InteropBitmap` object (`MyBitmap`) as the `_currentFrame`.

Comment: The snippet is pretty useless to guess what problem you are trying to solve.  But it is certainly going the wrong way around, you can only create a BitmapSource *from* an InteropBitmap, it does not support going from a BitmapSource *to* an InteropBitmap.  It is a helper class for the CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap/HIcon/MemorySection methods.

Comment: ok, I will try to change my architecture I working with classes from DLLs, it's an hard work to convert all the formats.